# How to find matrix A which multiplied by vector X returns the deviation of X from the mean?

Tags: matrices

I am new to linear algebra and I would appreciate help with the equation.
One needs to find the matrix А which multiplied by the vector X returns the deviation of X from the Mean:

*AX = X - Mean*.

Note, that the matrix А should not depend on the values of X, but only on its length, *n* (number of elements).

Comment: Deviation from the mean **of what**? Of $X$?

Comment: Of X from the mean (X-mean), or simply the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of $X=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$ is

$$m=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_i}{n}$$
and thereofore

$$x_i - m=x_i-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n x_i}{n}.$$

Finally $A$ is the matrix whose all entries are equal to $-\frac{1}{n}$ except the diagonals ones which are equal to $\frac{n-1}{n}$.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate how you obtained the final result?

Comment: The first column of $A$ is the image of $(1,0, \dots, 0)$. The second of $(0,1,0,\dots,0)$. And so on.

Comment: I sincerely apologize but how did you manage to eliminate the x's completely? For instance, xi−∑xi/n - how did you eliminate summation ∑xi and obtained the matrix A?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $J_n$ the $n \times n$ matrix with only ones. Then $A=I_n-\frac{1}{n}J_n$ might be what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am still looking into how to obtain the final result, though. I am not good at matrix manipulation and not sure how to simplify the original expression to get rid of all x'es.
If you don't mind, could you elaborate please?